# If-Statement in the middle of XML Linq Query

Tags: c#, .net, linq, xml-parsing, linq-to-xml

I know similar threads about if statements combined with Linq already exist, but in most cases, they recommend setting up the condition before the query.  In my case, the condition is an XML Element within the query.  So, I need to go through all the parent elements, and select a different child element depending on what the Parents contain.

Lets look at a sample of my xml file.  There are two different types of Properties: Uda and Template.  I need to get the Name ("TemplateName" or "UdaName") for both types of Properties.  The structure of the Properties is slightly different from one another, so I need a slightly different Linq query for each Property.

```
<PropertySet referenceId="column_common">
  <Name>Pset_ColumnCommon</Name>
  <Description>Common Properties to column elements</Description>
  <Properties>   
    <Property xsi:type="PropertySingleValueType" optional="true">
      <PropertyValue xsi:type="StringValueType" stringType="IfcIdentifier">
        <GetValue xsi:type="TemplateVariableType">
          <TemplateName>PART_POS</TemplateName>
        </GetValue>
      </PropertyValue>
    </Property>
    <Property xsi:type="PropertySingleValueType" optional="true">
      <PropertyValue xsi:type="BooleanValueType">
        <ValueConversion xsi:type="BooleanTypeFromIntegerVariable">
          <GetValue xsi:type="UdaVariableType">
            <UdaName>LOAD_BEARING</UdaName>
          </GetValue>
          <KeyValuePair>
            <Key>0</Key>
            <Value>false</Value>
          </KeyValuePair>
        </ValueConversion>
        <Default>true</Default>
      </PropertyValue>
    </Property>
  </Properties>
</PropertySet>
```

If they were all Template properties, I could simply use this Linq query to get the Names.

```
var propertyNames = from psetdefs in xElement.Elements(ns + "PropertySetDefinitions")
                    from pset in psetdefs.Elements(ns + "PropertySet")
                    where (string)pset.Attribute("referenceId").Value == PsetBinding
                    from props in pset.Elements(ns + "Properties")
                    from prop in props.Elements(ns + "Property")
                    from propValue in prop.Elements(ns + "PropertyValue")
                    from getValue in propValue.Elements(ns + "GetValue")
                    from templateName in getValue.Elements(ns + "TemplateName")
                    select templateName.Value;
```

I want to be able to put an if statement in the middle of the Linq query.  This is the logic I am trying to implement, but obviously it doesn't work:

```
var propertyNames = from psetdefs in xElement.Elements(ns + "PropertySetDefinitions")
                    from pset in psetdefs.Elements(ns + "PropertySet")
                    where (string)pset.Attribute("referenceId").Value == PsetBinding
                    from props in pset.Elements(ns + "Properties")
                    from prop in props.Elements(ns + "Property")
                    from propValue in prop.Elements(ns + "PropertyValue")
                                    

if (propValue.Contains(ns + "ValueConverstion"))
{
    from valCon in propValue.Elements(ns + "ValueConversion")
    from getValue in valCon.Elements(ns + "GetValue")
    from templateName in getValue.Elements(ns + "TemplateName")
    select templateName.Value;
}
else
{
    from getValue in propValue.Elements(ns + "GetValue")
    from templateName in getValue.Elements(ns + "TemplateName")
    select templateName.Value;
}
```

You can see that it has one extra element in the tree if it is a UdaProperty.  So the query becomes different.  How can I handle this?

Comment: Formatting the code snippets properly is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you considered using [XPath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/xml/select-nodes-using-xpath-navigation) instead?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to use the `DefaultIfEmpty` method:

```csharp
var propertyNames = from psetdefs in xElement.Elements(ns + "PropertySetDefinitions")
                    from pset in psetdefs.Elements(ns + "PropertySet")
                    where pset.Attribute("referenceId")?.Value == PsetBinding
                    from props in pset.Elements(ns + "Properties")
                    from prop in props.Elements(ns + "Property")
                    from propValue in prop.Elements(ns + "PropertyValue")
                    from valCon in propValue.Elements(ns + "ValueConverstion").DefaultIfEmpty(propValue)
                    from getValue in valCon.Elements(ns + "GetValue")
                    from templateName in getValue.Elements(ns + "TemplateName")
                    select templateName.Value;
```

Another option is to use ternary operator:

```
from valCon in (propValue.Contains("ValueConverstion") ? propValue.Elements(ns + "ValueConverstion") : new[] {propValue})
```

Finally XPath is easier `//GetValue/UdaName|//GetValue/TemplateName` will match your provided example file.

Comment: Also it will not work, the final label is `TemplateName` in the first case and `UdaName` in the second one.

Comment: Great!  That solves my problem!  Your solution works in this particular case.  But, Is there anyway to implement if statement logic in Linq?  I could see it being useful in certain cases.

Comment: I got it to work by just getting all the child elements of "GetValue."  In this case that works.

Comment: You can't put `if` in a linq query, but you can call a method that will.
There are typo too. `ValueConverstion` instead of `ValueConversion`

Comment: Remember that LINQ is about working with *sets* of data, so a `where` clause is the conditional operator and it's applied across the set. So you have to think in sets, and how each element is handled in sequence.